# Apache error on accessing Extension Manager in Typo3

Tags: apache, plugins, typo3

When i try to use the Extension Manager in Typo3, my Apache server crashes...

I use XAMPP.

This is my error log:

```
[di jan 13 20:43:53 2015] [notice] [] [pid 4928:tid 260] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) 
OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[di jan 13 20:43:53 2015] [notice] [] [pid 4928:tid 260] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[di jan 13 20:43:53 2015] [notice] [] [pid 4928:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[di jan 13 20:43:53 2015] [notice] [] [pid 4928:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7356
[di jan 13 20:43:55 2015] [notice] [] [pid 7356:tid 276] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I do not have any clue on what to do or what I can provide more to solve this problem. Anyone knows what to do?

Extra info:

- I did install curl. Curl is working.
- In php.ini: allow_url_fopen is on.
- Typo3 version: 6.2.9
- I work on a local typo3 environment. The site does work. It is on windows Vista.

What happens:

1) i click "extension manager"

2) i get the loader icon in the browser part where the extension should be loaded

3) i then get a Microsoft Windows popup screen: Apache HTTP Server has stopped working with these details:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.3.0
  Application Timestamp:    502f70a3
  Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.4.7.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   505114f8
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 00039eaa
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1043
  Additional Information 1: fd00
  Additional Information 2: ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160
  Additional Information 3: fd00
  Additional Information 4: ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160
```

4) at that point there is no info added to the apache error log

5) now i close the pop up

6) then the previous mentioned lines are added to the error log (restarting apache)

When i check my browser network, the error happens on this GET:

```
http://typo3t1.local/typo3/mod.php?M=tools_ExtensionmanagerExtensionmanager&moduleToken=22799cc88caf7817031b07bc69ad0235b0474d5e
```

with this response:

```
(failed)
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Comment: Yo showed us that your Apache started... great, but it would be better to describe the ... _crash_, does it show any message in browser? Has your TYPO3 any version at all?

Comment: As it's a windows machine: check if curl is installed / configured or if it's not installed, hcek your php.ini settings for [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/de/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Comment: Thanks. I did edit my post (hope that is the way it should be done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the sollution. Add these lines to httpd.conf:

```
# 8388608 = 8*1024*1024
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Restart Apache.

I got this from here:
http://www.adick.at/2012/10/02/apache-crash-php5ts-dll/

It seems to be a "Stack Overflow" :)